# Lua garbage collector crash with lots of yieldk

Tags: c, lua

I am using Lua 5.4.6 with the following program:

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

#define YIELD_MAX 1000000

typedef struct {
        int counter;
} user_context_t;



static int contfunc1(lua_State *L, int, long int)
{
        printf("continuation function called\n");
        lua_getglobal(L, "ctx");
        user_context_t *c = (user_context_t *)lua_touserdata(L, -1);
        c->counter++;
        if (c->counter < YIELD_MAX) {
                return lua_yieldk(L, 0, 0, contfunc1);
        }
        return 0;
}


static int libfunc1(lua_State *L)
{
        printf("libfunc1 called\n");
        lua_getglobal(L, "ctx");
        user_context_t *c = (user_context_t *)lua_touserdata(L, -1);
        if (c->counter < YIELD_MAX) {
                return lua_yieldk(L, 0, 0, contfunc1);
        } else {
                return lua_yield(L, 0);
        }
}


const luaL_Reg libfuncs[] = {{"func1", libfunc1}, {NULL, NULL}};


const char *lua_prog = R"luaprog(
test.func1()
test.func1()
)luaprog";

static user_context_t ctx;

int main(void)
{
        lua_State *L;

        L = luaL_newstate();
        luaL_newlib(L, libfuncs);
        lua_setglobal(L, "test");
        lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void *)&ctx);
        lua_setglobal(L, "ctx");

        luaL_loadstring(L, lua_prog);

        int n, err;
lresume:
        err = lua_resume(L, NULL, 0, &n);
        switch (err) {
        case LUA_YIELD:
                goto lresume;
        case LUA_OK:
                break;
        default:
                const char *s = lua_tostring(L, -1);
                printf("LUA error: %s\n", s);
                break;
        }

        lua_close(L);

        return 0;
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
libfunc1 called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
continuation function called
LUA error: attempt to index a nil value

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7f6034b in deletelist (limit=0x5555555592a8, p=0x2b, L=0x5555555592a8)
    at /usr/src/debug/lua/lua-5.4.6/src/lgc.c:1498
Downloading source file /usr/src/debug/lua/lua-5.4.6/src/lgc.c
1498        GCObject *next = p->next;
```

Does anyone know why this happens after a certain amount of yieldk iterations? As I understand it, yieldk uses longjmp and this just replaces the stack frame...
There shouldn't be any Lua objects created on the fly and being garbage collected anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, after

```
lua_getglobal(L, "ctx");
user_context_t *c = (user_context_t *)lua_touserdata(L, -1);
```

I must add

```
lua_remove(L, -1);
```

Otherwise Lua runs out of stack :( Stupid mistake.